# how to retrive the paticular record in any of the field in the db.?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

we are new one for progress, we like to retrive a particular record in the existing db, fox ex: if we have a 500 records in that record i need to retrive exactly one record. for this what can i do..?
please help us with sample code..

we fetch our code here..

```
def var sum as int. 
def var a   as int no-undo. 
def var i   as int no-undo. 
for each po_mstr break by po_nbr. /select count from po_mstr./ assign a = 583. 
    if first-of (po_nbr) then 
    do i = 1 to a:enter code here if (i = 1) then sum = sum + 1. 
        if (sum = 400)
            then disp po_nbr po_vend po_ship po_ord_date. 
    end. 
end.
```

Comment: Question is not clear. If you want one record out of 500 then there should be a filter condition. What's that?

Answer (score 2):

You need a WHERE clause in your FOR EACH statement.

For example if you want po-nbr 123 you might code:

```
FOR EACH po_mstr NO-LOCK WHERE po_mstr.po_nbr = 123:
  DISPLAY
    po_nbr po_vend po_ship po_ord_date
  .
END.
```

Also -- if you only want a single, unique record you could code:

```
FIND po_mstr NO-LOCK  WHERE po_mstr.po_nbr = 123 NO-ERROR.
IF AVAILABLE( po_mstr ) THEN
  DISPLAY
    po_nbr po_vend po_ship po_ord_date
  .
```